# QT qmake GRPC implementation

Tags: c++, qt, grpc, qmake

I want to implement GRPC on my qt project but first I try run a grpc example but I get undefined reference error.

main.cpp:

```
#include <helloworld.grpc.pb.h>

#include <grpc/grpc.h>
#include <grpcpp/server_builder.h>

#include <iostream>

class GreeterService final : public helloworld::Greeter::Service {
public:
  virtual ::grpc::Status SayHello(::grpc::ServerContext* context, const ::helloworld::HelloRequest* request, ::helloworld::HelloReply* response) {
    std::cout << "Server: message for \"" << request->name() << "\"." << std::endl;

    response->set_message("Hi " + request->name());

    return grpc::Status::OK;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
  builder.AddListeningPort("0.0.0.0:50051", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());

  GreeterService my_service;
  builder.RegisterService(&my_service);

  std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
  server->Wait();

  return 0;
}
```

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \

INCLUDEPATH += /home/grpc/include \
               /home/grpc/
DEPENDPATH  += /home/grpc//include \
               /home/grpc/
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,"path_to_libgrpc++.so.1.45"
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++` -L/usr/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu


# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Error:

```
undefined reference to `helloworld::Greeter::Service::Service()'
```

I don't know why I get this error, compailer can see headers main also can see. But I think there are missing things in my .pro file

Comment: `helloworld::Greeter::Service` should not have helloworld in it

Comment: When I add helloworld doesn't change anything

Comment: Make it just Greeter::Service, you are inside the directory

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'Greeter'; did you mean 'helloworld::Greeter'? (fix available)
helloworld.grpc.pb.h:31:7: 'helloworld::Greeter' declared here
change 'Greeter' to 'helloworld::Greeter'

Comment: `rpath` here specifies the search path to the linker for shared libraries at runtime. Try removing one, two, or all CMAKE flags from the `.pro` file. Compiler may see it, but maybe linker cannot.

Comment: Doesn't change anything  :(

Comment: I suspect you are using a sample for the initial code. Are you willing to go with a new setup? What kind of QT application you have? I ran the helloworld sample from grpc c++ example and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Do you run it with qt using qmake ?          I just want to see grpc working on qt using qmake    If you do it can you share it in github and link me on answer ?

Comment: Somewhere there must be a conversion from gRPC and/or protobuf *.proto files from protobuf syntax to (here C++) chosen programming language. This is done through ‘protoc’ executable. It gives you additional generated source code .pb.cc and .pb.h to add to your compilation and then other object files for the linker

Comment: This is not that easy:
https://github.com/jmesmon/qmake-protobuf-example/blob/master/protobuf.pri

Comment: @NGI I think you should make these 2 comments the answer. This appropriately answers the question.

Comment: @Milan Š I am still in the process of building a complete answer at the present time as I want to post an answer that at least "worked on my machine".
A third comment maybe : was not Qmake being to be be de-comisionned in favor of Cmake ? Maybe we (anyone first) have(has) to provide both answer: one with qmake and one with cmake.

Comment: CMake is well documented for gRPC. As for QT IIRC - QT5 supported CMake and was suggesting it's use (however it didn't integrate well with their tools) and QT6 should be as you say mostly using CMake (but it's been some time since I worked with QT and I might be wrong) as to why the author uses qmake - I do not know. Might be a legacy application or perhaps management doesn't want to adopt CMake:)

Comment: " or perhaps management doesn't want to adopt CMake"  :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is likely due to the fact that you are not linking against the gRPC library correctly.

*To fix this, you need to make sure that you are linking against the gRPC library in your project file (.pro). You can do this by adding the following lines to your .pro file:*

```
LIBS += -lgrpc++
```

This will tell the linker to link against the gRPC C++ library, which includes the helloworld::Greeter::Service class that you are trying to use.

*You may also need to specify the path to the library if it is not in a standard library search path. You can do this by adding the following line to your .pro file:*

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/libgrpc++.so
```

Replace /path/to/libgrpc++.so with the actual path to the libgrpc++.so library on your system.

Once you have added these lines to your .pro file, try rebuilding your project. This should resolve the undefined reference error.

Comment: He is linking against grpc in this line: `LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++` the `pkg-config --libs grpc++` does exactly what you outlined in your answer.